# Splines with controllable degree but auto-generation of knots in R

Tags: r, regression, splines

I'm using `smooth.spline` with some success, but I need to control the degree of the regressions between knots (cubic is too high for my needs).  I looked at the [`bs`](http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~dhunter/R/html/splines/html/bs.html) function, which allows controllable degree but requires manual specification of knot locations. Is there a function in R which will find knots for me automatically, but let me control the degree of the inter-knot regressions (not sure if this is the right term...)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, you don't "find knots" automatically.  There are a few ways, but nothing truly optimal.  Much more often you use a smoothing spline.  For most functional smoothing splines the algorithm just spams ~50-100 knots across the support of your variable.  It then uses a penalty on the size of the coefficients for each of the basis functions to bring the non-linearity under control.  Most implementations optimize this single penalty via some manner of information criterion.

In R, arguable the most mature package would be `mgcv`.  You usually specify a model via `gam` (or `bam` for 10k+ obs).  In the formula, you can use `s(x)` terms to specify smooth terms (non-linear terms).  There are far too many types of smoothers to discuss them all, but they are all well documented.  I do not believe the default `bs='tp'` allows linear or quadratic penalties as you requested.  However, when properly penalized, the resulting smoother generally looks just fine with the default cubic-order penalty.  If you really want to explore linear or quadratic penalties you can read more about `bs='ps'` in `mgcv`.

When using `mgcv`, be sure to set a comfortably large initial k so it can model severe non-linearity if it is present.  Think of k as the number of knots spammed across the support before the penalties are evaluated.  You specify it inside a `s()` term.

I've also had solid luck with a much simpler natural spline from the base `splines` package.  Just using a `ns(x,df=4)` in a model formula gives very sane results in most cases.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I'll check out `MGCV`.

Comment: note the package name is in lower case, mgcv